# Unity.Не работает код

Tags: c#, unity3d

Смотрите моя проблема звучит так (редактор Visual Studio никаких ошибок не выдает ,но юнити говорит что есть ,прошу глянуть что может быть не так)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed, tilt;
    private Vector3 target = new Vector3(0, 1.39f, 0);
    void Update () {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        if (transform.position == target && target.y != 0.1f)
            target.y = 0.1f;
        else if (transform.position == target && target.y == 0.1f)
            target.y = 1.39;

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * tilt);





    }
}
```

Comment: а сообщения об ошибках есть?

Comment: @ExplodingKitteт нету

Comment: speed и tilt проинициализируй

Comment: @Kamushek поправьте код

Comment: Покажите что вам пишет юнити насчёт этого

Comment: А ошибка, скриншот, описание не?

Answer (score 0):

Вы умножаете на tilt, однако он у вас нигде не проинициализирован, по хорошему, студия должна сообщить об ошибке(подсветить tilt в выражении умножения).
Измените

`public float speed, tilt;`

на

`public float speed, tilt = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
target.y = 1.39;
```

вот здесь ты присваиваешь переменной типа float значение типа double 
так не получится 
поэтому надо дописать буковку f , этим ты скажешь компилятору, что число имеет тип float:

```
target.y = 1.39f;
```